# Does querySelector on an Event Object search the DOM?

Tags: reactjs, dom, eventhandler, selectors-api

Here's the question in more detail. Say, you have an event handler

```
const eventHandy = (e) =>{
 //do stuff;
}
```

Within eventHandy, you run a querySelector on e.target

```
const eventHandy = (e) =>{
 e.target.querySelectorAll("div");
}
```

The question is does this querySelector do a query on the DOM or the event object e.target?

For context, and without getting too much into details; we have a react app. We are doing some stuff with accessibility and focus. Part of our code is finding focusable elements. On one side of the debate, doing DOM queries inside of a React app is an anti-pattern, and therefore should be avoided at all cost. On the other side, there are times when DOM queries are necessary and shouldn't be discounted. However, there is a portion of code that gets an event object and runs querySelectorAll.. This is a sticking point for some of our developers.

Comment: Are you suggesting you are handling events on elements not added to DOM, so only in memory, and asking if the query selector works in such case?

Otherwise I am not sure if I understand what you mean by *DOM or the event object e.target*, I mean, `e.target` is an element in DOM, no?

Comment: @JakubKotrs Hi, I'll try to make it plain. I'm sure you know, but for clarity: DOM Queries are the methods that are called on the DOM to select and return one or more of the elements represented in the DOM. However, when you trigger an event, you get the target element and all of its children. So If you run a query on the target element,, are you again reaching out to the Document Object Model or are you querying the target element for its children. I dont know how to state the quetion any more plainly. But this is the debate at my job.

Comment: You are querying the Document Object Model which the target element is a part of of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySelector does a query on the event object e.target and will find all elements within the target, not on the parent document.

Comment: This is what I thought, but my Senior Developer insisted that e,target.querySelectorAll("some_selector") is a DOM query, not a query on the event object.

Comment: yes, e,target.querySelectorAll("some_selector") is a DOM query.
its a query on e.target which is also a DOM element but event object is not a dom element its just an event object, we cannot do e.querySelectorAll("some_selector").